# Why does mysql service stop when 100 users are connected

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed mysql server 5.0 on windows server 2008 R2 64bit OS.
max_connection set to 1000 but when 95-100 user connected at a time service stooped. Please help me. I have the following setting in `my.ini` please check Server have 16GB of RAM

```
default-storage-engine=INNODB
max_connections=1000<br>
query_cache_size=0<br>
table_cache=256<br>
tmp_table_size=5M<br>
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G<br>
myisam_max_extra_sort_file_size=100G<br>
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M<br>
key_buffer_size=1000M<br>
read_buffer_size=64K<br>
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K<br>
sort_buffer_size=212M<br>
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M<br>
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1<br>
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M<br>
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M<br>
innodb_log_file_size=10M<br>
innodb_thread_concurrency=10<br>
connect_timeout=60<br>
interactive_timeout=60<br>
wait_timeout=60<br>
```

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your log files ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your OS max connection. You could set your max-connection in MySQL to whatever number you want but, if it is more than max connection of your OS then you can't go above that.

Comment: where and how to check os max connection?

Comment: have re-installed mysql server and problem solved